# Filtered Twitter Stream API consume in Android app using Retrofit and coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, twitter, retrofit, coroutine

I want to consume filtered Twitter V2 stream in the android app. But not able to understand how to achieve this using retrofit and coroutine. Please help

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to import retrofit and kotlinx_coroutine_android in your app build.gradle file, in dependency part.

Then after coding data class and response model parts you need to define api function in interface, but remember to use 'suspend' instead of callback like below:

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("users")
    suspend fun getUsers(): List<User>

}
```

Then you can get api response in a suspend function in repository like below:

```
class MainRepository(private val apiHelper: ApiHelper) {

    suspend fun getUsers() = apiHelper.getUsers()
}
```

Then in viewmodel get data from repository like below:

```
class MainViewModel(private val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun getUsers() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.success(data = mainRepository.getUsers()))
    }
}
```

(Try to use more state to control loading and error and even use try/catch block to control bugs)

And finally, in your UI observe request response like below:

```
viewModel.getUsers().observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { resource ->
                    recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    resource.data?.let { users -> retrieveList(users) }                
            }
        }
    })
```

I supposed that you know complete process of requesting to a webservice and then I just explained differences between using callback and using suspend functions.
If it was not enough clear, message me to explain more.